# A certain property for Heegaard splittings

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

I've become interested in 3-manifolds with the following property (called 'Property A'): let $c_{i}$ be a set of $g$ curves on a genus $g$ surface $\Sigma$ and let $b_{i}$ be the $g$ meridional curves of $\Sigma$. That is, if $\Sigma$ is the boundary of a genus $g$ handlebody, then the $b_{i}$ bound compressing disks. Then $\{c_{i}\}_{i=1,\dots,g}$ satisfy 'Property A' if, for any $b_{j}$, the geometric intersection numbers $\iota(c_{i}, b_{j})$ have the same sign for all $i=1,\dots,g$. Informally, all of the attaching curves for the 2-handles run over the 1-handles in the same direction.

So my question is, which 3-manifolds admit a Heegaard splitting with the attaching curves of the 2-handles satisfy Property A?

For example, any direct sum of lens spaces will satisfy this. As does the following Heegaard diagram for the Poincaré homology sphere (taken from Manifold atlas http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Poincar%C3%A9%27s_homology_sphere):

[image]

A possible nonexample could be the 3-torus, for which the only Heegaard diagram I know does not satisfy this property.

Lastly, and of course this depends heavily on my first question, is it possible that all rational homology spheres satisfy this?

I would be grateful for any sort of insight.

Comment: I think that this is true for all 3-manifolds, at the cost of increasing the genus. At the group presentation level, you're replacing an occurrence of $a^{-1}$ with a new generator $x$ and a relation $ax$. At the geometric level, you can stabilise near a negative intersection point and replace it with two positive ones.

Comment: I think you are right. However, if I do this stabilisation, I think I can find another $b'_{j}\in [b_{j}]\in H_{1}(\Sigma)$ where we will have intersections with opposite signs. This wasn't my original question though. What I really mean is my informal statement that all 2-handles run over the 1-handles in the same direction, so for this, I need my $b_{j}$ to vary in some sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Property A is the same as positive diagrams by Hempel.

*Hempel, John*, [**Positive diagrams for Seifert fibered spaces.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641(01)00024-4), Topology Appl. 117, No. 3, 319-334 (2002). [ZBL1051.57024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1051.57024).